Extract IP address of a transaction
Is there a way to determine the IP address of the submitter of a Solana transaction using on-chain information? I'm trying to track down the source of a set of transactions.

No, you cannot. IP address is not included in any transaction details. IP address can only be obtained via the client side, and programs cannot know where the client that initialized the transaction belongs to. Unless, you build a program which has a state account that stores IP information which is passed by the client or the program mentions it in the transaction logs.
But ultimately, any transaction by default does not contain IP information.
